# keep space between div's

Tags: html, css, element

I want show a html div which contains a state-description with a circle (green or red). This circle shows the state of the engine in the right corner of the description.

My problem is the following. If the windows size has changed (smaller), the description and the "state-circle" overlap each other.

How can I prevent this?
Do you know how the CSS-code should be?

structure is mainly this:

```css
.statusdiv{
    height: 40px;

}
.statusbeschreibung{

    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
.statuskreis {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    top: 13px;
    /*left: 190px;*/
    margin-left: 60%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 12.5px;
}

.status-on{
    background-color: green;
}
.status-off{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="list-block">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="statusdiv">
                                <p class="statusbeschreibung">Motorstatus</p>
                                <div name="motorstatus" id="motorstatus" class="item-link statuskreis status-off"></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried any CSS? can you share that code?

Comment: Please post code rather than a picture, and tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: code is uploaded. I am new here. Don't know how to write code in a post.

Comment: Tried to give both inner div's a fixed or absolute position, tried to give them margins and tried to put them in a grid

Comment: I have added a snippet to your answer, please edit it to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was based on your original screenshot images of your code: basically you should use `display:inline-block` instead of `position:absolute` to prevent your bullet from overlapping your text, and then use a margin-left on the bullet so that it always has enough space between it and the text.

```css
.list-block ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-block li {
  list-style: none;
}

.statusdiv {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.statusbeschreibung {
  margin-left: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.statuskreis {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.status-on {
  background-color: green;
}
.status-off {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="statusdiv">
        <p class="statusbeschreibung">Motorstatus</p>
        <div name="motorstatus" id="motorstatus" class="item-link statuskreis status-off"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="statusdiv">
        <p class="statusbeschreibung">Motorstatus</p>
        <div name="motorstatus" id="motorstatus" class="item-link statuskreis status-on"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it correctly, you style the circle  with the class "motortatus".

Try to set the width and height in percentages, not in pixels. This should resize the status circle and prevent it from overlapping with the description, except the font of the description doensn't resize at all and fills up the whole div.

Comment: No worries, the down-vote is not mine, but as the question takes shape, you can edit your answer to give a valuable edition to Stack Overflow's knowledge base, and I am sure whoever gave this answer a thumbs down, will revert the action.

Comment: "Try to set the width and height in percentages, not in pixels." - That is a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

I love inline lists for this sort of thing, but you can also do columns in your preferred css framework of choice.

I've styled it so each of the two list items is 50% of the width of the ul container, but you can tweak those as you see fit.

```css
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.statusdiv {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2d2d2d;
}

.statusdiv li {
width: 50%;
float: left;
padding: 0 1em;
}

.statusdiv li:first-child {
text-align: right;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
}

.statusdiv li:last-child {
text-align: left;
}

.circle {
content: "";
background-color: aqua;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- EDIT THIS SNIPPET -->
<ul class="statusdiv">
  <li>
    Status thing:
  </li>
  <li><span class="circle"></span></li>
</ul>
```